# NodeJS child_process.spawn() Error opening terminal: unknown

Tags: node.js, terminal, child-process, ubuntu-server

I'm trying to execute simple program "htop" from NodeJS using "child_process".spawn() method, On my local Ubuntu Desktop it works fine, but when I move code to Ubuntu server (digital ocean) , child_process exits with code 1: "Error opening terminal: unknown." Here is simple code example

```
   const { spawnSync, spawn } = require('child_process');
    const htop = spawn("htop", [], {
        detached: true, 
        shell: false, 
        windowsHide: true,
    });

    htop.stdout.on('data', (dataBuffer) => {
        socket.emit('htop log', dataBuffer.toString());
    });
```

Does anybody have some idea what should be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried if setting `shell: true` helps?

Comment: Yes I did, It didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Solved, In case anybody needs it in future, Just use  [NodePTY](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pty) package instead of child_process.spawn(), It works fine for me